# Silverlight 4 Key Event at Control Level

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight control (ChildWindow) that I want to receive all key down events. The problem is that if I simply say

```
this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(EventDetailsPopup_UC_KeyDown)
```

it won't work because the event is routed to all of its child controls. How do I receive Key or Mouse events from the UserControl or ChildWindow level? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You do not describe what you mean by "it won't work", but I can at least give you some background.

Silverlight supports the concept of Routed Events. When a routed event is fired on a child control, it is passes up the logical tree, firing on the control's parent, then the parent's parent etc ... until the root visual is met. The list of routed events is detailed on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189018%28VS.95%29.aspx#routed_events). This is called **bubbling**.

It looks like you want to prevent a child control from seeing this event? i.e. you want to cancel it by setting it as handled. Unfortunately this is not possible because the child control will always receive the event first. To support this you require a feature called **tunneling**, where a 'preview' event first tunnels from parent to child before the bubbling event is fired. This is a WPF-specific feature as described in the MSDN page referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

Or if "wont work" means that you are not getting the event.
It may be beacause some child element has setted Handled parameter of eventarguments to true.

But you can still register for listening handled events in code lets say in constructor of your childwindow:

```
this.AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)YourHandlerFunction, true);
```

Comment: Correct, "won't work" means that the root control does not get the event because one of its children handled it. I have many child controls nested in the main control, so going through each child control and each of its components and setting them as un-handled would get a bit messy. Just wondering if there was a way for the root control to still receive this event without knowing of its child controls. Thanks